# how to write condition using ternary operator in javascript Es6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am writing one ternary condition in react mapStatetoprops function , while returning the object i want to write some condition to full fill return data

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 const { module: { module1, module4: { submodule } } } = state;
 const newObj = { module1, module4Submodule: submodule };
 return{
   testmodule: newobj
  }
 }
```

newobj returns

```
{
"module1": {
"foo": 1,
"bar": 2,
"anotherfoo": 5
},
"module4Submodule": {
"foo": 9,
"bar": 0,
"anotherfoo": 1
}
}
```

condition to be written in testmodule is

> if  state.manage.module contains "module1" OR "module4Submodule" (need to check
> length, null, undefined value for module1 and module4Submodule)then return
> "newobj" else return "somevalue"

also is this good way to write condition in return statement or write condition before that and just return value

Comment: Just use an `if` statement if you don't feel comfortable writing a conditional expression.

Comment: @Bergi Just want to try with ternary operator, i can use if  and else condition , trying to learn

Comment: Then please post the working code with an `if`/`else` so that we know what code to transform.

Comment: Where is `obj` coming from? Is it supposed to be `state`? As @Bergi said, write it with `if / else` and then replace with `? :` (I believe however that readability is key and that code shouldn't necessarily be a oneliner, that's for the uglification) (again depends on the scenario)

Comment: @Icepickle i have edited  the code, yes it is from the state

Answer (score 1):

You say you need something like this

> if state.manage.module contains "module1" OR "module4Submodule" (need
> to check length, null, undefined value for module1 and
> module4Submodule)then return "newobj" else return "somevalue"

take a look at the code below.

But I must stress that in this case it would be better to use ' classic ' if/else statement as it's a complex condition and very hard to ' read ' by you or others.

```js
const newObj = {
  "module1": {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2,
    "anotherfoo": 5
  },
  "module4Submodule": {
    "foo": 9,
    "bar": 0,
    "anotherfoo": 1
  }
}
const returnResult = (Object.keys(newObj).includes('module1') && Object.keys(newObj.module1) && Object.keys(newObj.module1).length > 0) || (Object.keys(newObj).includes('module4Submodule') && Object.keys(newObj.module4Submodule) && Object.keys(newObj.module4Submodule).length > 0) ? newObj : 'someValue'

console.log(returnResult)
```